# How to open and save files

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3

Is there a way to quickly open files in sublime text2?

At the moment I open files like this.

I open my terminal and enter 
`subl source/myproj/myfile.rs`

Can I do this inside of **sublime text2/3**?

Also when I want to create a new file in `source/myproj/` I usally press `ctrl + n` to create a new window and then I hit `ctrl + s` to save and name the file. The problem is when I hit `ctrl + s` my file system dialog opens and I have to use my mouse.

I think I saw someone using vim and he just could say `source/myproj/mynewfile.rs` and then the file would be created.

Is this possible in sublime text 2/3?

Comment: It kind of sounds like you want a keyboard-only, command-line text editor, but I don't think Sublime was originally intended for that. vim/emacs are some of the few editors designed for that type of editing. Sublime does have its own pop-up command line that you can open with Ctrl-~, but it may not be able to do all the things you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

To quickly open a file in your current project, you can hit `Ctrl+P` and start writing the filename. This will sort through the files in your project and give you a little list, most likely the one you are looking for is pre selected, but if not, it is somewhere near the topmost options to select from, use arrow key down and highlight it, press enter and you just opened that file.

Another option to quickly create a file is using the [AdvancedNewFile plugin](https://github.com/skuroda/Sublime-AdvancedNewFile).

When you hit `Ctrl+n`, it asks near the bottom of the window for a path and filename, once you enter it, it opens the new tab with the file already created, not an untitled file to later use system dialog to save to disk.